# Dealing with Arrays and Aggregation In a RDLC Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, rdlc

I'm trying to create a report using RDLC from VS2012.
I've created a dataset from my object which contains all the data to be displayed in report. However this object has some attributes which are arrays and others which are custom objects (aggregation).

```
public class myObject2Report {

private Double [] myResults;
private FakeDataObject fake;

//...
}
```

The problem is I can't add the array indexes individually to a table in report, neither add a sub-field from my FakeDataObject. I tryed in a report design view, but without success and now a I'm looking for some information to create a expression to do it like:

```
=Fields!myResults[0].Value
=Fields!myResults[1].Value
//...
```

OR

```
=Fields!FakeDataObject.subField1.Value
=Fields!FakeDataObject.subField2.Value
//...
```

Any help in this subject would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can access an array with the following syntax (note: VS shows a redline in the editor, but it still works):

```
=Fields!myResults.Value(0)
=Fields!myResults.Value(1)
```

Nested object seem unsupported, see these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895030/binding-object-data-source-with-nested-list-objects-in-rdlc) and [here(indicates that it should work in VS2010 SP1, it does not work for me in VS2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551969/child-objects-in-rdlc-studio-2010rc). The solution is to flat the objects.

Comment: Thanks, @Florian. One oddity: the expression editor shows the `(0)` underlined in red but it works fine when you run the report.